# Registration form validation error

Tags: php, mysql, registration

This is my registration.php

```
include("config.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit'],$_POST['fullname'],$_POST['username'], $_POST['password'],         $_POST['email'], $_POST['role']))
{
    $submit=$_POST['submit'];
    $date=date("y-m-d");
    $fullname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fullname']);
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $role = (int)$_POST['role'];

    if($submit)
    {
        if($fullname&&$username&&$password&&$email&&$emp_role)
        {

            $sql="INSERT INTO `logindetails` (fullname,username, password, email,     emp_role,$date) VALUES ('$fullname',$username', '$password','$email','$emp_role','$date')";

            $result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

            echo "<h1>you have registered sucessfully</h1>";

            echo "<a href='login.php'>go to login page</a>";

        }
        else
        {
            echo "Please fill in <b>all</b>fields!";
        }
    }
}
```

Are there any errors in this code? If I submit the form I'm not getting any message. Is this code right or is there anything I missed for validation?

I created table with `id`, `username`, `password`, `date`, `role`, `fullname`, `email`

Comment: What is `$_POST['submit']` supposed to represent?

Comment: Please provide the HTML code of the form.

Comment: "You are not getting any message" as in "everything seems to work" or as in "I'm expecting messages but I get none at all and nothing seems to be happening and I have already tried to debug and looked at the error messages but I seem to have a problem in part x"?

Comment: i created for submit button in the form

Comment: @Tim: that usually means that you want to check whether the submit button was used to submit a form and not another button. I.e, if the HTML does contain a submit button with the name `submit` this code probably doesn't fly.

Comment: how to send the html form code

Comment: The real question should be: is the code executed at all? Also of interest: is the `die`-statement called, is there any message in the log, is the connection with the database correct, is there other code in the site that works but only this one fails etc, etc?

Comment: @user1160249: on the bottom-left of your question you'll see an edit-button, use that for adding the HTML code to the question.

Comment: <form method="POST" action="registrationform.php">

<fieldset>
  <legend>Registration Form</legend>

  <p>
  <label>FullName</label>
  <input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" /><br /><br />
  
  
  <label>UserName</label>
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
  
  <label><br />
    <br />
    Password   </label>
    <input type="text" id="password" name="password" /><br /><br />

Comment: <label>Email</label>
  <input type"text" id="email" name="email" /><br /><br />
  
  <label> Role</label>
  <input type="radio" name="emp_role" value="orange" >orange
  
  <input type="radio" name="role" value="white" >white
<input type="radio" name="role" value="black" >black<br />

 

                     <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Register" />
  
</fieldset>
</form>

</body>






</body>

</html>

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's a request for general code review. There is a Code Review discussion elsewhere on Stack Exchange, but the Stack Overview area isn't it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't get any results maybe because some of your conditionals aren't true ... put an ending "else" condition for each if/else statement . You have 2 if/else conditionals that don't have any "else" ending condition.
Here is where you missed else : if(isset(post[]) etc... ) { } and for the if($submit) {}

If you would put an else condition to each if/else statement ( ex. : else { echo "condition failed" } ) i bet you would surely get a result

Comment: if(isset($_POST['submit'],$_POST['fullname'],$_POST['username'], $_POST['password'],         $_POST['email'], $_POST['role']))
{} else { echo "name, username, pass, email, role have not been set yet"; }

Comment: if($submit) {} else {echo 'post[submit] might have a FALSE value';} These are just examples to test your code nothing more

Comment: yes the code is good ... but like i said before , end those conditionals with and else {} statement

Answer (score 0):

You haven't done something stupid like forget to set the method of the form, have you?

Does your form element say something like?:

```
<form name="registration" action="registration.php" method="POST">
```

Comment: yes i gave...................